# How to delete entities in a chained one-to-many and many-to-many JPA relationship

Tags: jpa, spring-data-jpa, eclipselink

I have a chain of entities as follows:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Patients")
public class Patient extends TimeStampedPersistable{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="patient", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @PrivateOwned
    private List<Insurance> insurances; 
}


    @Entity
    @Table(name = "insurance")
    public class Insurance extends PersistableEntity {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        
        @ManyToOne(optional=false) 
        @JoinColumn(name="patient_id", nullable=false)
        private Patient patient;
    
        @Column(name = "policy_number", unique = false, nullable = true)
        private String policyNumber;
        
        @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
        @JoinTable(name = "insurance_companycodes", joinColumns = {
                @JoinColumn(name = "insurance_id", referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = false, updatable = false) }, inverseJoinColumns = {
                        @JoinColumn(name = "insuranceCompanyCode_id", referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = false, updatable = false) })  
        private Set<InsuranceCompanyCode> insuranceCompanyCodes = new HashSet<>();
}
    


@Entity
@Table(name = "insurance_company_codes")
public class InsuranceCompanyCode extends PersistableEntity {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    
    @Column(name = "identifier", unique = true, nullable = true)
    private String identifier;
    
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "insuranceCompanyCodes", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<Insurance> insurances = new HashSet<>();
}
```

I need to remove insurance items from the Patient object.  I am using the following code:

```
    for (Iterator<Insurance> iterator = patient.getInsurances().iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
        iterator.next();
        iterator.remove();
    }
```

This seems to work for child entities that don't have child entities, however in this situation the Insurance entity has child entities and is not actually removed (no exceptions are displayed).  Note, I am using the EclipseLink specific annotation @PrivateOwned which I expected would have forced the removal of the Insurance entities.

Any guidance, suggestions appreciated!

Comment: I would have expected it to work as well, but you have a circular reference which can cause strange things when object identity isn't maintained. Turn on EclipseLink logging to finest and check out when the insurances list is fetched, and make sure that the patient.insurances.get(i).patient == patient. If it doesn't, it could force that other patient instance into the persistence unit if you ever call merge, causing confusion between the two insurances lists. This could occur if you read in a patient and then clear the entity manager before fetching lazy relationships.

Comment: Or do you mean it only works for Insurance that don't have InsuranceCompanyCodes? You don't have anything that tells JPA what to do in such a situation, and since InsuranceCompanyCode has a reference to Insurance with cascade persist, such a situation will resurrect any removed Insurance. You need to clean up those references before you can delete the Insurance object.